# Is there any evidence to suggest how long has Maz Kanata had the bar?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

[This site](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata) states:

> Around **thirty years** after the Battle of Endor, she owned a castle which played host to travelers, smugglers, and others.

[This site](http://www.bustle.com/articles/131319-who-is-maz-kanata-the-mysterious-space-pirate-is-instrumental-to-the-force-awakens) states:

> She's had this watering hole for **about a century**,

My question is: **Is there any evidence to suggest how long has Maz Kanata had the bar??**

Comment: In the movie, Han says she’s run it for a thousand years.

Comment: Note that the wiki doesn't state how long she owned her cantina, merely that she still owned it "30 years after the Battle of Endor"

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - in the script, Abrams says the same so Han is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very clearly stated that she's run the bar for about 1000 years.

When Finn asks where Han's brought them, he explains that Maz has been running this cantina for a thousand years. The exact quote (from the novelization) doesn't leave much room for interpretation:

> “The galaxy’s full of watering holes, but nothing like this place. It’s been run by an old smuggler named Maz Kanata for a thousand years.

Unfortunately, the second source you quoted seems to contradict this:

> "Her history is that she was a pirate for a long time. She's lived over a thousand years. She's had this watering hole for about a century, and it's like another bar that you'd find in a corner of the Star Wars universe."

That quote comes from an [*Entertainment Weekly* interview](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-force-awakens-lupita-nyongo-maz-kanata) with Abrams prior to the release of the movie. Abrams may have misspoke, or the script may have changed in the interim, but the evidence in the final movie has to take precedence over anything else.

Comment: I never ever thought I'd say this, but Abrams makes me miss Lucas.

Comment: He doesn't seem to be much of a "details guy". Probably explains *Lost*. Still, Lucas is responsible for *The Phantom Menace*.

Comment: I'm pretending that was an evil clone Luucas.

Comment: @DVK : I'd have to agree.