# How old is Maz Kanata?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens* we meet Maz Kanata for the first time.

Do we know exactly **how old she is?**

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Is there any evidence to suggest how long has Maz Kanata had the bar?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112154/is-there-any-evidence-to-suggest-how-long-has-maz-kanata-had-the-bar)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### More than a thousand years.

From the canonical [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/maz-kanata):

> Maz Kanata is more than a thousand years old, a diminutive being with vast experience at surviving in the underworld. From her castle on Takodana, Maz has seen galactic powers rise and fall and felt the Force ebb and flow, seeking an elusive balance between darkness and light. She has given many a young smuggler a start by offering credits, equipment or connections, and helped many an old friend rediscover a lost path.

We may find out more than this in the future. [According to JJ Abrams](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-force-awakens-lupita-nyongo-maz-kanata), her backstory will definitely be developed further:

> What kind of species is she? What is her homeworld? “All that backstory will be forthcoming,” Abrams says. “In the movie, you don’t learn these things, but I know that these are things that are coming out in other venues.” So keep your own eyes out for more of Maz’s past to be fleshed out in books or games.

Comment: Too slow, G.I. Joe.

Comment: Nice answer! UV

Comment: It would be funny if this answer would be not only the most upvoted, but also an accepted one.

Comment: @daerdemandt - I've come to the conclusion that a lot of people a) Vote for the first one on the list and don't scroll down and b) Don't up vote my answers because they feel that I've "got enough rep already" :-)

Comment: @Daerdemandt Prepare to be amused ...

Answer (score 11):

The [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/maz-kanata) lists her age as being over a millennium. No *specific* birth-date is given, but she's a bit older than Yoda.

> ***Maz Kanata is more than a thousand years old,** a diminutive being with
> vast experience at surviving in the underworld. From her castle on
> Takodana, Maz has seen galactic powers rise and fall and felt the
> Force ebb and flow, seeking an elusive balance between darkness and
> light. She has given many a young smuggler a start by offering
> credits, equipment or connections, and helped many an old friend
> rediscover a lost path.*

Director JJ Abrams confirmed this in an interview:

> Abrams was willing to go a little further and reveal some of the
> backstory behind Kanata and the castle she inhabits with a court of
> misfits and miscreants. *“Her history is that she was a pirate for a
> long time,”* he says. *“**She’s lived over a thousand years.** She’s had
> this watering hole for about a century, and it’s like another bar that
> you’d find in a corner of the Star Wars universe.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens: J.J. Abrams reveals backstory of alien Maz Kanata](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-force-awakens-lupita-nyongo-maz-kanata)</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice answer! UV

Comment: It's worth noting that that particular quote from Abrams has been contradicted by the novelisation of TFA itself - see [Mike's answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112157/31394). The "about a century" part being wrong makes the whole quote slightly suspect (although of course the "over a thousand years" part is confirmed by the Databank quote).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes, but the OP isn't asking about the bar, they're asking about the age of the owner.

Comment: I know; I'm just saying that the quote as a whole doesn't work very well as confirmation since another part of it is wrong. Not that this invalidates your answer or anything - just worth mentioning.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Fair enough. I'm assuming that Jar Jar misspoke when he said about her having the bar for a thousand years.

Comment: -1 for annoying, seemingly self righteous personal prejudice.

Comment: @xavon_Wrentaile - Happy now?